# AWS Load Balancer - Remove cache elements on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm currenty upscaling from 1xEC2 server to:
1xLoad Balancer
2xEC2 servers

I have quiet a lot of customers, each running our service on their own domain.
We have a webfront and admin-interface and use a lot of caching. When something is changed on the admin-part, the server calls eg.: customer.net/cacheutil.ashx?f=delete&obj=objectname to remove the object on crossdomains.

Hence the new setup, I don't know how to do this with multiple servers, ensuring that the cached objects is deleted on both servers (or more, if we choose to launch more).
I think that it is a "bit much" to require our customers to add eg. "web1.customer.net", "web2.customer.net" and "customer.net" to point at 3 different DNS CNAMEs, since they are not that IT experienced.

How does anyone else do this?

Comment: it depends on your architecture.  If it is read heavy and the "admin" only has a relatively small number of requests then establish a way that all requests for "admin" go to node1, then alter the program code on node1 so that it duplicates the request to node2.  There maybe a problem with nodes being out of sync with this simple approach.  If read and write are equal then you probably have to rearchitect your whole app to use a scalable, shareable backing store

Comment: Move your cache off your webservers and into ElastiCache

Answer (score 2):

When scaling horizontally, it is recommended to **keep your web servers stateless**. That is, do not store data on a specific server. Instead, store the information in a database or cache that can be accessed by all servers. (eg DynamoDB, ElastiCache)

Alternatively, use the **Sticky Sessions** feature of the Elastic Load Balancing service, which uses a cookie to always redirect a user's connection back to the same server.

See documentation: [Configure Sticky Sessions for Your Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html)